# How to change this javascript module to a revealing module pattern?

Tags: javascript

I have the following code:

server.js:

```
var http = require("http");

function start() {
    function onRequest(request, response) {
        console.log("Request received.");
        response.writeHead(200, { "Content-Type": "text/plain" });
        response.write("Hello World");
        response.end();
    }

    http.createServer(onRequest).listen(8888);

    console.log("Server has started.");
}
exports.start = start;
```

index.js:

```
var server = require('./server');
server.start();
```

I try to turn the server.js into a revealing module pattern:

```
var http = require("http");

var server = function() {
    function start() {
        function onRequest(request, response) {
            console.log("Request received.");
            response.writeHead(200, { "Content-Type": "text/plain" });
            response.write("Hello World");
            response.end();
        }

        http.createServer(onRequest).listen(8888);

        console.log("Server has started.");
    }

    return {
        start: start
    };
}();
```

but I get an error: `TypeError: server.start is not a function`

What mistake(s) am I making?

Thanks.

Comment: Why do this? This is just moving backwards in time, to before we had nice things, like actual modules.

Comment: You are not exporting `server`? `var server = require('./server');` will import an empty object since your module doesn't `export` anything. You know that variables in modules are *local* to modules? Only what is exported can be accessed by other modules. So adding an IIFE here to reduce the scope `start` doesn't add any value. It really just makes the code unnecessarily complex.

Comment: Could you provide some explanation of what you mean by "actual modules"?  I'm not trying to make it unnecessarily complex, but I thought that the Revealing Module Pattern was supposed to help that?

Answer (score 2):

You forgot to export your module

```
exports = server;
```